# libexpect sigalrm nanosleep crash

Tags: linux, multithreading, signals, sleep

I'm working with libexpect, but if the read times out (expected return code EXP_TIMEOUT) I instead get a crash as follows.

```
    Program terminated with signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
#0  0x00007f1366275bb9 in __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:56
56  ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007f1366275bb9 in __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:56
#1  0x00007f1366278fc8 in __GI_abort () at abort.c:89
#2  0x00007f13662b2e14 in __libc_message (do_abort=do_abort@entry=2, fmt=fmt@entry=0x7f13663bf06b "*** %s ***: %s terminated\n") at ../sysdeps/posix/libc_fatal.c:175
#3  0x00007f136634a7dc in __GI___fortify_fail (msg=<optimized out>) at fortify_fail.c:37
#4  0x00007f136634a6ed in ____longjmp_chk () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/____longjmp_chk.S:100
#5  0x00007f136634a649 in __longjmp_chk (env=0x1, val=1) at ../setjmp/longjmp.c:38
#6  0x00007f1366ed2a95 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libexpect.so.5.45
#7  <signal handler called>
#8  0x00007f1367334b9d in nanosleep () at ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S:81
#9  0x000000000044cc13 in main (argc=3, argv=0x7fffca4013b8) at main_thread.c:6750
(gdb)
```

As you can see, I'm using nanosleep, which is supposed to not interact with signals like usleep and sleep (http://linux.die.net/man/2/nanosleep). As I understand it, libexpect uses SIGALRM to time out, but it's unclear to me how the two threads are interacting. If I had to guess, the expect call is raising a sigalrm, and it's interrupting the nanosleep call, but beyond that I don't know what's going on.

Thread 1:

```
while (stuff)
{
    //dothings
    struct timespec time;
    time.tv_sec = 0.25;
    time.tv_nsec = 250000000;
    nanosleep(&time, NULL);
}
```

Thread 2:

```
switch(exp_expectl(fd, exp_glob, (char*)user_prompt, OK, exp_end))
{
case OK:
    DG_LOG_DEBUG("Recieved user prompt");
    break;
case EXP_TIMEOUT:
    DG_LOG_DEBUG("Expect timed out");
    goto error;
default:
    DG_LOG_DEBUG("Expect failed for unknown reasons");
    goto error;
}
```

I have done some reading about signals and sleep, but I've used sleep in multiple threads on many occasions and had no difficulties until now. What am I missing?

`edit: misc version info
ubuntu 14.04 3.13.0-44-generic
/usr/lib/libexpect.so.5.45
code is in C
compiler is gcc (-lexpect -ltcl)
include <tcl8.6/expect.h>`

Comment: What is thread 2 doing after `goto error`?

Comment: Why are you trying to assign a double to a `timespec.tv_sec`?

Comment: @Dan `error:
  if (E_NONE != e)
  {
      log_error("Failed to run %s", program);
      dg_pthread_mutex_unlock(&expect_lock);
  }

  return e == E_NONE && (WEXITSTATUS(status) == 0);`

I just noticed that i don't waitpid on error. Could that be the issue?

Comment: I've debugged it and the crash occurs on the call to exp_expectl, so I don't think we are reaching any of the subsequent code.